# how to set overlay for div on click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a image1 when mouse overlay on image1 image2 want to appear with a close(X) button at the bottom right corner of the image2. if i click the close button the image2 will disappear image1 want to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example..

**HTML:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
      <img id="main" src="http://www.clayton.edu/portals/53/images/icon_Google_Chrome.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay">
      <div id="close"> X </div>
      <img  src="http://rocketdock.com/images/screenshots/Google-Chrome-Icon-3.png" />   
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay {
 position: absolute;  
 top: 0;
 display:none;
}

#main {   
   margin-top: 10px; 
}

#close{
  float:right;   
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").mouseenter(function() {
               $("#overlay").show();
               $("#main").hide();
    });
    $("#close").click(function() { 
               $("#overlay").hide();
               $("#main").show();
    });
 });
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tbb8c4me/2/)**

Comment: sorry i think the demo link was empty. please send me the correct demo fiddle.

Comment: thanks .. with a doubt in that. how can i use it for multiple "divs". i have 10 images how can i do it for all the images with the single method.

Comment: this one will get the id of the hovered image: https://jsfiddle.net/tbb8c4me/6/

Comment: super working perfect.. but i need  overlay image is different for the 10 images. in simple i have 10 images and 10 overlap images. how to assign the corresponding overlap for the images

Comment: It might help for you get an idea.. https://jsfiddle.net/tbb8c4me/12/

Comment: Thank you for your help... its working super.. i want exactly this ... i understand completely .. thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

your ans. is here

jsfiddle.net/istvanv/uQj7t/28/

replace mouseover to click

Comment: i did this "http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/". i need text caption on image during hover. thanks in advance